# UART Configuration for custom bittage

Tags: uart, data-transfer

How does one configure the UART for custom data/parity/stop bits? If you give an example, can you make it 115200/16/none/1? OS is raspbian on A+

Answer (score 1):

The 115200, none, 1 part can be done with the stty command (man stty).

The standard drivers/UART do not support 16 bits.

If 16 is a serious number you might be able to bit bang with my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.  See e.g. [gpioSerialOpen](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSerialReadOpen) and [gpioWaveAddSerial](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioWaveAddSerial).

However don't expect a great deal of reliablity at 115200bps.

Comment: The values I included are GBA serial "multiboot" values. Also, will over clocking help?

Comment: I know nothing of GBA serial multiboot.  Overclocking won't affect the standard Linux drivers.  It may make pigpio report errors faster.

Comment: multiboot is an alternative way of loading programs onto a GBA, which is through the i/o port